# When should use lazy loading to load images?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For instance,If the image download from the server we should load the image lazily. and i want to know the other instances.

Comment: Your question is way too broad (and my guess is that you know that) and/or irrelevant. Voting to close as not a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It couldn't hurt to always do this. All of the devices coming out lately benefit from multi-core CPUs. Grand central dispatch makes it easy to define a process that will be executed on another core, and then synch it up to the main thread for UI udpates, when done.

If you do this your application will feel more responsive, and also will be easy to move from say local disk access to remote access of resources.

***Example:***

```
 dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(taskQ, ^
    {
        //Do some work. . . . 

        //Now update back on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {

        });
    });


    //release the queue.
```

Answer (score 2):

Any time when the image isn't already in active memory and ready to display.

If you're loading the image from disk or from core data it wouldn't hurt to lazy load it and use a placeholder image until it's done.

Especially for UITableView when you're displaying an image at maybe 100x100 and the actual image is 1000x1000.

Do the resizing in the BG and when it's done present the small image.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of lazy loading is that you only load resources as of when you need them. For instance, if you have a lot of images/resources in your application bundle you could load them all as soon as the app starts, having everything hit memory at the same time. This is a bad idea as it not only uses a lot of RAM (quite unnecessarily as well, as its not all on screen at the same time), but can take a long time to load.

Answer (score 0):

If your action in getting the message and displaying it will take a noticeable amount of time on the main thread and block your app, then you should perform your action on a background thread.